# declare Global variable in Android Service

Tags: android, variables, service, bluetooth

I am working on developing an Android App to communicate with sensor via bluetooth.

I am attaching a snap shot of my code. This is written inside Service

I want My Android Mobile Screen get locked when I give a tap (value of g force >0.5 g (yAccel>500 in code)) on my sensor and it should get unlocked (after locked once) when i tap my sensor with less than 0.1g.

My Logic implementation: I declared a variable called lockStatus (initialize = 2). Once tap detected, set lockStatus = 1 and Lock screen (screenLock.class), keep checking if it is already locked and second tap of < 0.1 g detected. unlock it.
If it is already locked and no tap detected, keep it in locked condition (screenLock.class)

Problem in my case:
As far as I keep on applying > 0.5g force, the screen gets locked (ScreenLock.class), the moment i reduce it from 0.5g, screen gets unlocked.

Reason: This is written inside Service (as Bluetooth Service should keep on running). So the moment, next data (no tap even after first lock) is sent via bluetooth of my sensor, the lockStatus settles to 2 and it goes in else block and screen gets unlocked.

Where can I declare my Global Variable lockStatus, so that it does not get initialized  every time I call my Service (BLEService)?

```
public class BLEService extends Service {

   public static BLEService singleInstance;

   private final static String logTag = BLEService.class.getSimpleName();

   public int lockStatus = 2;

   //// Section of Code of My Logic

   if ((checksum_362 & 0x80) == 128) showAlert = true;

    if (yAccel > 500 || yAccel < -500)
    {
            gMeasure = true;
            lockStatus = 1; //lock done;
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenLock.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            //delay for min 10 min


    }
    else
    {
        if (lockStatus == 1)
        {
            if (yAccel < 100 || yAccel > -100)
            {
                //UnLock
                lockStatus = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                gMeasure = true;
                lockStatus = 1; //lock done;
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ScreenLock.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }

    ChartActivity.singleInstance.newChartData(xAccel, yAccel, zAccel, showAlert, gMeasure);
    GoogleDriveService.singleInstance.newLogData(xAccel, yAccel, zAccel, showAlert);
```

Comment: you can use application class that extends Application. -http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton that provide your variable and init it in application

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        InitYourSingleton
    }

}
```

Comment: The Android `Application` class *IS* a singleton. The OP may as well simply maintain their variable in the `Application` if they're going to extend it.